# Send data from server to client upon loading page nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, express

I have an endpoint defined as such on my server side:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(densityList);
});
```

When I hit `http://localhost:port/`, if I am not incorrect, this is the endpoint that's hit on the server.

Upon hitting the homepage, I wish to send to the client a globally defined densityList (which will have been populated) that will be used by the client to populate a map.

This is my client side code:

```
  <script>          

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.get('/', {}, function(data){

            L.map.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw'

            console.log("before creating map");
            console.log(data);

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([37.8, -96], 4); 

            console.log("creating map")
            L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox.streets'
            }).addTo(mymap);

            var heat = L.heatLayer(data, {radius: 25}).addTo(mymap);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I believed that this line of code should capture whatever the server sends:

```
$.get('/', {}, function(data){
```

However, when I do:

```
console.log(data)
```

the entire html file prints. Can somebody advise on how to send this data on the first hit of the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `{}` from `$.get() syntax` it should be like as this :

```
$.get("/", function(data, status){
L.map.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw'

            console.log("before creating map");
            console.log(data);

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([37.8, -96], 4); 

            console.log("creating map")
            L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox.streets'
            }).addTo(mymap);

            var heat = L.heatLayer(data, {radius: 25}).addTo(mymap);
            console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: kashap, unfortunately that didn't do it. I still happen to print my html file as data. :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange routing and static files properly like this question: [node.js and express: possible to skip from route back to middleware (static)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769456/node-js-and-express-possible-to-skip-from-route-back-to-middleware-static)

For example, you can include some parameters in `$.get` and do some condition checks in router definition.